# Error in adding AFNetworking framework in the project

Tags: ios

Adding AFNetworking framework in the project I got the following errors:-

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass", referenced from:
      _AFContentTypeForPathExtension in AFURLRequestSerialization.o
  "_UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag", referenced from:
      _AFContentTypeForPathExtension in AFURLRequestSerialization.o
  "_kUTTagClassFilenameExtension", referenced from:
      _AFContentTypeForPathExtension in AFURLRequestSerialization.o
  "_kUTTagClassMIMEType", referenced from:
      _AFContentTypeForPathExtension in AFURLRequestSerialization.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am using xcode 4.5 with sdk iOS 6.0

Comment: have you added all the necessery framework?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Add following frameworks in your project:

```
MobileCoreServices.framework
SystemConfiguration.framework
```

Comment: That's it, I forgot the MobileCoreServices and thought it's related to iOS 7! thanks man, save me some time.